# Dynamic filter in angular is duplicating filters

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a dynamic filter for my angular app which is looking for registered systems in the app array (enum), and uses them to display the filter. Everything started to work fine, however, when I change tabs the filter is duplicating the filters - I'm getting two arrays in console log. I don't know what exactly is causing this, but I guess the problem is with the for loop in this mechanism.

page.component.ts

```
  private setupShowroomTypeFilter() {
    const supportedTargetTypes: SupportedTargetType[] = this.showroomService.getWizardSupportedTargetTypes();

    for (const supportedTargetType of supportedTargetTypes) {
      const targetTypeFilter: LabeledInstallationStatusFilter = new LabeledInstallationStatusFilter(
        ShowroomNames[supportedTargetType.targetTypeCode],
        installationStatus => installationStatus.showroom.targetType === supportedTargetType.targetTypeCode
      );
      TARGET_TYPE_FILTERS.push();
    }
  }
```

enum

```
export interface SupportedTargetType {
  targetTypeCode: string;
  component: Type<any>;
}
```

static filter - all

```
export let TARGET_TYPE_FILTERS: LabeledInstallationStatusFilter[] = [
  {
    label: 'All',
    filter: () => true
  }
];
```

Comment: Why is the value passed in `TARGET_TYPE_FILTERS.push();` empty?

Comment: What exactly calls the function `setupShowroomTypeFilter`? If it's called from `subscribe` or in `pipe` of some `Observable` it is possible that you are not unsubscribing correctly.

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    this.setupShowroomTypeFilter();
    this.setupMyInstallations();